# Xerces parser for UTF -8 Encoding

Tags: xerces, domparser

I have cpp code which is used to read xml files, parse data and then store it in table.
Initially data was ASCII encoded but now it is UTF8 encoded.
code is using Xerces c++ , can some help where it looks for the encoding while parsing?

Answer (score 0):

In the document header or prolog.